# WP7 achieving "pushed in" effect on active items

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do you achieve the "pushed in" effect on active items.

To clarify what I mean when you touch one of the live tiles, the tile becomes skewed depending on the touch placement.

Is this available out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **TiltEffect** which is part of the [Silverlight Toolkit for WP7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com). There is a post on [WindowsPhoneGeek.com](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Silverlight-for-WP7-Toolkit-TiltEffect-in-depth) that explains how to use it.